# load jQuery from external source if not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, document.write

**load jQuery from source**

What I like to do is to drop my local jquery.js and have
it hosted somewhere else. But what if Google is down? So
let's code a fallback that uses another source if jQuery
is "still" not loaded...

I made this test case but it does not seem to work, maybe
someone can help me out:

http://jsfiddle.net/RBz4n

Comment: Can you please be a little more explicit with what you want to do?

Comment: Google being down would result in the internet imploding. No worries.

Comment: A CDN such as Google's is highly unlikely to go down. Coding around such an unlikely event will probably just pollute your code :(

Answer (score 7):

This works fairly well (from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)):

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: That's a beaut!  Thanks a ton!  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pure javascript solution that starts out by detecting if jQuery is available. If not, it tries the CDN version. If that's not available, it tries the local version. Handles 404 errors. I use this in a solution that doesn't know whether the website has included jQuery.

```
<script>
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  loadjQuery("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", verifyJQueryCdnLoaded);
} else 
  main();

function verifyJQueryCdnLoaded() {
  if (typeof jQuery === "undefined")
    loadjQuery("script/jquery-1.6.1.js", main);
  else
    main();
}

function loadjQuery(url, callback) {
  var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
  script_tag.setAttribute("src", url)
  script_tag.onload = callback; // Run callback once jQuery has loaded
  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // Same thing but for IE
    if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') callback();
  }
  script_tag.onerror = function() {
    loadjQuery("script/jquery-1.6.1.js", main);
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
}

function main() {
  if (typeof jQuery === "undefined")
    alert("jQuery not loaded.");

  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Rest of your code here...
  });

}

</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use something like this while writing a bookmarklet to be used with JIRA.  The "typeof jQuery === 'undefined'" test always failed.  It turned out that JIRA was using some scripts that use jQuery, like FancyBox, which caused "jQuery" to be defined as a function, but "$" still wasn't defined.  I changed the test in the condition and jQuery would be loaded properly.

Comment: Wow. I've never seen so much code used to solve such a simple problem. You must love typing... :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your script is that you're not waiting for the script to load before testing whether jQuery has been loaded.  Use something like this instead:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
            callback();
        }
    }
    script.onload = callback;
    script.src = src;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function isjQueryLoaded() {
    return (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined');
}

function tryLoadChain() {
    var chain = arguments;
    if (!isjQueryLoaded()) {
        if (chain.length) {
            loadScript(
                chain[0],
                function() {
                    tryLoadChain.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(chain, 1));
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert('not loaded!');
        }
    } else {
        alert('loaded!');
    }
}

tryLoadChain(
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js',
    'http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js',
    'mine.js');
```

Comment: mhhh - i can even delete tryLoadChain's sources and your script still alerts: loaded... not working for me

Comment: no it doesn't. Change the first URL so you'll get a 404. It will just stop executing. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

If you use Firebug and see where jQuery gets loaded you can see taht Google successfully loaded it. Why it doesn't seem to work? Because requests are asynchronous and while your script runs synchronously it executes all steps before the first script gets loaded.

So:

1. jQuery not present.
2. Add SCRIPT element to load from Google (browser sends a request and continues execution of the script)
3. jQuery not present add another source
4. ...

etc etc.

### Solution

What you should do is attach to `onLoad` event of your script loading elements and check for jQuery after they've loaded.

Script executes lightning fast compared to sending a request out to some server on the internet and getting results back for processing.

### Additional notes

As I've read you're going to have problems detecting 404s using this technique. Suggested way would be to use Ajax (XHR) and then attach script element and add received content to it. This would be the most reliable way of doing it for all browsers.

Comment: so a setTimeOut before checking if jQuery is loaded can help?

Answer (score 0):

Roger's answer is rediculous.  Here, use this instead, its 2 lines.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: There are a lot of good ways to append a script node to the DOM. `document.write` is not among them.

Comment: @editor - Care to explain? Because almost all the answers posted here rely on document.write() and this seems to be the standard way of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

In short, because it gives you the ability to write directly to the page, it is very easily abused, and if misabused, potentially a security hole.  It got downvoted here because there are usually nicer ways to do the same thing.  

As a side note, for a large project, look into AMD style loading, possibly with something like require.js.

Comment: @RobertChrist - By the way, in that post itself it says that this is one of the legitimate uses of document.write..