# Script does not function when dynamically including jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a script that I'm trying to modify so that I don't load the jQuery library if its already present. However, the only way I can get things to work is example 1 below (explictly loading the jQuery library). When I try to conditionally load it, the slider does not work...

Example #1 - the slider works fine in this example (but jQuery may be loaded multiple times)

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/js/slider/jquery.slider.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(
            function(){
                jQuery('#accordion-1').slider({
                    autoStart:true,
                    slideInterval:5000,
                    slideNum:false
                });
            })
    </script>
</head>
```

Example #2 - Trying to dynamically load jQuery. Slider does not work.

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
            // jQuery is not loaded => load it:
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/js/slider/jquery.slider.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(
            function(){
                jQuery('#accordion-1').slider({
                    autoStart:true,
                    slideInterval:5000,
                    slideNum:false
                });
            })
    </script>
</head>
```

Example #3 - This does not work either...

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
            document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
        }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/js/slider/jquery.slider.js'></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to basically wait for the script to load. Please take a look at the below code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function initSlider(){
            jQuery(document).ready(
            function(){
                jQuery('#accordion-1').slider({
                    autoStart:true,
                    slideInterval:5000,
                    slideNum:false
                });
            })
        }
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
            // jQuery is not loaded => load it:
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
            script.onreadystatechange= function () {//This is for IE
               if (this.readyState == 'complete'){ initSlider(); };
            }
            script.onload= initSlider;//This is for Non-IE
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a working answer because as far as I know you should not use "script.onload" You should really be using script.addEventListener('load', initSlider, false); and I'm pretty sure the readyState you are looking for is 'loaded' and not 'complete.' Further on that, are we not looking for a numeric value returned to readyState, in this case 2 for 'loaded' or 4 for 'complete?'

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are appending the jQuery script to the end of the `body`.  This is *after* the `script` elements that use jQuery. That obviously won't work, since scripts are evaluated sequentially.

You should use `document.write` instead (one of the rare occasions where that is correct):

```
document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
```

The `unescape` code is the easy way around the fact that `</script>` will cause errors if inserted directly into Javascript.

This code inserts the `script` tag right at the current point in the document. (Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523263/load-jquery-from-external-source-if-not-loaded).)

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. See my updated question (Example #3)

Answer (score 0):

Instead try:

```
    var script = document.createElement("script");

script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js";

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Won't work before your body element has been added to the DOM. Try just:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(!window.jQuery)
            document.write('<script src="jquery.js.php"><\/script>');
    </script>
```