# if jquery doesn't load then load jquery from here

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [load jQuery from external source if not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523263/load-jquery-from-external-source-if-not-loaded)

How can I set up a backup if jquery doesn't load?

I've found and tried this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert('jquery didn't load !');
    loadScript("/here/jquery.min.js");
    .... // this is where i'd want to say load from '/here/jquery.js'
}
```

but I don't know how to call the src of a script within a script.

Comment: try the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415821/jquery-from-cdn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly common:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: YES! exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Look here [How can I load jQuery if it is not already loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813114/how-can-i-load-jquery-if-it-is-not-already-loaded) or [load jQuery from external source if not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523263/load-jquery-from-external-source-if-not-loaded)

```
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'jquery.js';
    jqTag.onload = myJQueryCode;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a div in regular HTML that says jquery didn't load , then hide it with jquery

```
<div class="jqueryError">
  <a> jquery did not load </a>
</div>

$(function(){
  $('jqueryError').hide();
});
```

Comment: doesn't really answer my question of how to load jquery again from within a script

Comment: The problem with this is that even if jquery is loaded the user will see the notification until it has actually loaded. Not the biggest deal in the world but...

Comment: yea, i was using that for testing the scripts :)

Comment: I just saw the alert part, use Johan's answer then

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to load jquery if you are connected to the internet?

You could try this:

```
function loadJQuery() {
  if (navigator.onLine(connected)) {
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('jquery_loader').src = '/javascripts/jquery.js';
  }
 }
```

Remember though, if you are testing offline you could use this, but it would be useless on a website, because everyone will be connected to the internet in order to visit your website.