# How to call another Jquery function from a different file

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have 2 js files one is the reusable js function . I would like to call file2.js functions in file1.js . But its not invoking the function from file2.js
function

please find my below code for

**file1.js**

```js
<script src="/sites/ECM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ECM/SiteAssets/Jquery/file2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

ArrangeChoices("Check Boxes",4);
});

</script>
```

**file2.js**

```js
<script src="/sites/ECM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ECM/SiteAssets/Jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


});

function ArrangeChoices(cName,count)
{
alert(cName - count);
$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
 columnName: cName,
 perRow: count
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: You are using script tags inside of a javascript file. I don't think this will work to begin with. The files included at the top should be included from your HTML file while the javascript files should have no HTML tags.

Comment: Hi pcnate Thanks for your reply These files are used in sharepoint and this is how it will be done in SharePoint for adding Javascript if i include the code in one file it is working fine.

Comment: Is the function accessible from a Chrome console?

Comment: but it is throwing error saying that the function is undefined  [link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/296kleb.jpg) see the error message screen shot

Comment: Likely, what is going on is that jquery is being loaded by a js file and not ready when you setup the document.ready. You may have to resort to including the 2nd file as you do jquery from the first file. I have in the past manually loaded jquery into a sharepoint page via javascript via a method like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523263/load-jquery-from-external-source-if-not-loaded). Then execute a function as a callback once that has completed loading and call your function then.

Answer (score 0):

You included `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` for both js file. Get rid of one in file1.js.

Comment: This is avoiding the fact that these are javascript files.

Comment: I have commented out one of the jquery-1.11.2.min.js from file1.js but still its not invoking the function from file2                                         <script src="/sites/ECMPOC/kranthi/SiteAssets/Jquery/ArrangeChoices.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


ArrangeChoices("Check Boxes",4);


</script>